# Unity,Error trying to shoot something in a 3d isometric game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 3d isometric game and I'm trying to shoot things from player to a direction taked with a joystick and I would like that it shoots when I release the joystick. You can easly search Brawl Stars video to understand better what I mean. The first script is of the joystick and the second for the shoot(I putted it inside the player). It now gives me this error: the object you want to instantiate is null.

Joystick's script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class rightjoystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
private Image bgImg;
private Image joystickImg;
private Vector3 inputVector;

private void Start()
{
    bgImg = GetComponent<Image>();
    joystickImg = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
}

public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
{
    Vector2 pos;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(bgImg.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {
        pos.x = (pos.x / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

        inputVector = new Vector3(pos.x * 2, 0, pos.y * 2);
        inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

        // Move joystickImg
        joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition =
            new Vector3(inputVector.x * bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3
                , inputVector.z * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 3));

    }
}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
{
    OnDrag(ped);
}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
{
    inputVector = Vector3.zero;
    joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
}

public float Horizontal()
{
    if (inputVector.x != 0)
        return inputVector.x;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

public float Vertical()
{
    if (inputVector.z != 0)
        return inputVector.z;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}
}
```

shooting script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody proiettile;
public float launchForce = 70f;
public rightjoystick moveJoystick;
private Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

public void Update()
{
    dir.x = moveJoystick.Horizontal();
    dir.z = moveJoystick.Vertical();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var projectileInstance = Instantiate(proiettile);
    projectileInstance.AddForce(dir * launchForce);
}
}
```

Comment: proiettile is a rigidbody, thats a component not a gameobject.. you need to instantiate the game object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class shoot : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
private Image bgImg;
private Image joystickImg;
private Vector3 inputVector;
public Rigidbody proiettile;
private Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
private Vector3 newpos;
public float launchForce;
public Rigidbody Player;
private Rigidbody clone;

private void Start()
{
    bgImg = GetComponent<Image>();
    joystickImg = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
}

public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
{
    Vector2 pos;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(bgImg.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {
        pos.x = (pos.x / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

        inputVector = new Vector3(pos.x * 2 +1, 0, pos.y * 2 - 1);
        inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

        // Move joystickImg
        joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition =
            new Vector3(inputVector.x * bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3
                , inputVector.z * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 3));

    }
}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
{
    OnDrag(ped);
}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
{
    dir.x = Horizontal();
    dir.z = Vertical();
    newpos = dir * (launchForce);
    clone = Instantiate(proiettile, Player.transform.position, Player.transform.rotation);

    clone.transform.position=Vector3.MoveTowards(Player.transform.position,newpos,10f);
    // joystick come back to start position
    inputVector = Vector3.zero;
    joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
    clone.timeoutDestructor = 5;
}

public float Horizontal()
{
    if (inputVector.x != 0)
        return inputVector.x;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

public float Vertical()
{
    if (inputVector.z != 0)
        return inputVector.z;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}
}
```